# Cambiar de fragment con container se muestra vacío

Tags: android, android-fragment

A ver si alguien es capaz de ver el error, llevo horas aquí y no sé por qué no se muestra la pantalla de municipios, es decir se muestra en blanco.
La idea es hacer click en una provincia y mostrar la lista de municipios.

**Fragment de municipios**

```
public class MunicipioFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private IOnClickMunicipio mListener;
    String provincia;
    String searchText;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public MunicipioFragment() {
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_municipio_list, container, false);

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
             recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }

            //Para la provincia
            provincia = getArguments().getString(Constantes.ARG_PROVINCIA);

            //Para el buscador de municipios
            searchText = getArguments().getString(Constantes.ARG_TEXTO_BUSCAR);

            if (provincia != null) {
                mListener.stTitleItemProvincia(provincia);
                List<String> listaMunicipios = getArguments().getStringArrayList(Constantes.ARG_LOCALIDADES);

                List<Municipio> municipios = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String municipio : listaMunicipios) {
                    municipios.add(new Municipio(municipio));
                }

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyMunicipioRecyclerViewAdapter(municipios, mListener));
            }

            if (searchText != null) {
                new getMunicipiosTask().execute(searchText);
            }

        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof IOnClickMunicipio) {
            mListener = (IOnClickMunicipio) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement IOnClickMunicipio");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    private class getMunicipiosTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Municipio>> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Buscando...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Municipio> doInBackground(String... params) {
            Serializer serializer = new Persister();
            String strQuery = params[0];

            try {
                //Buscando el código del municipio
                String urlEncoded = "http://www.salesianos-triana.com/dam/xml/municipios/?ciudad=" + URLEncoder.encode(strQuery, "utf-8");

                URL urlFinal = new URL(urlEncoded);

                InputStream inputStream = urlFinal.openStream();

                Municipios municipios = serializer.read(Municipios.class, inputStream, false);

                List<Municipio> listaMunicipios = municipios.getListaMunicipios();

                return listaMunicipios;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<Municipio> municipios) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if (municipios == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sin coincidencias...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyMunicipioRecyclerViewAdapter(municipios, mListener));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Adapter de municipios**

```
public class MyMunicipioRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyMunicipioRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Municipio> mValues;
    private final IOnClickMunicipio mListener;

    public MyMunicipioRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Municipio> items, IOnClickMunicipio listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_municipio_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.textViewMunicipio.setText(holder.mItem.getNombre());

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onLocalidadClick(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;

        public final TextView textViewMunicipio;
        public Municipio mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;

            textViewMunicipio = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_nombre_municipio);
        }

    }
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
    public void onProvinciaClick(String provincia, ArrayList<String> municipios) {
        Fragment fragment = new MunicipioFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(Constantes.ARG_PROVINCIA, provincia);
        args.putStringArrayList(Constantes.ARG_LOCALIDADES, municipios);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

**XML activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.aemet.jose.clienteaemet.MainActivity">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"   />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Revisaste si tienes datos en tu respuesta del _AsyncTask_?

Comment: Sí, tengo datos. por eso me extraña

Comment: Si hay data, ¿como se ve **layout _fragment_municipio_item.xml_**?

Comment: ¿Lo comprobaste en _onBindViewHolder_ comprobando el contenido de _mItem.getNombre()_?

Comment: Nada el error estaba en que en las clases modelo no estaban bien implementadas las etiquetas y claro, me mostraba todo vacía, muchas gracias por responder @StefanNolde

Comment: Si ya lo resolviste comparte la respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta correcta al planteamiento de la duda está en las anotaciones de las clases modelo. Es decir, los argumentos no daban error y el AsyncTask está correcto, lo único que fallaba eran las clases modelo, que alguna no tenía puestas las anotaciones correctamente. Remarco que mis clases modelo van con Parceler. Hay que revisarlas bien para no volverse loco. Saludos.